# Cassandra query very slow when database is large

Tags: cassandra

I have a table with 45 million keys.
Compaction strategy is LCS.
Single node Cassandra version 2.0.5.
No key or row caching.

Queries are very slow. They were several times faster when the database was smaller.

```
activity                                                                                       | timestamp    | source      | source_elapsed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+-------------+----------------
                                                                            execute_cql3_query | 17:47:07,891 | 10.72.9.151 |              0
Parsing select * from object_version_info where key = 'test10-Client9_99900' LIMIT 10000; | 17:47:07,891 | 10.72.9.151 |             80
                                                                           Preparing statement | 17:47:07,891 | 10.72.9.151 |            178
                                  Executing single-partition query on object_version_info | 17:47:07,893 | 10.72.9.151 |           2513
                                                                  Acquiring sstable references | 17:47:07,893 | 10.72.9.151 |           2539
                                                                   Merging memtable tombstones | 17:47:07,893 | 10.72.9.151 |           2597
                                                     Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1517 | 17:47:07,893 | 10.72.9.151 |           2652
                                                     Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1482 | 17:47:07,893 | 10.72.9.151 |           2677
                                         Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1268 | 17:47:08,560 | 10.72.9.151 |         669935
                                                   Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 17:47:08,560 | 10.72.9.151 |         669956
                     Skipped 0/3 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 17:47:09,411 | 10.72.9.151 |        1520279
                                                    Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 17:47:09,411 | 10.72.9.151 |        1520302
                                                            Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 17:47:09,411 | 10.72.9.151 |        1520351
                                                                              Request complete | 17:47:09,411 | 10.72.9.151 |        1520615
```

Comment: its very hard to read that trace, can you put it in a code block?

Comment: Could you please post the output of ``bin/nodetool cfhistograms <your keyspase> object_version_info`` ?

Comment: No much luck with the formatting. But if you copy and paste the trace to an editor it looks better.

Comment: Do any queries do table scans?

Comment: cfhistograms show: Offset = 8 / Cell Count = 46986498 and Offset = 446 / Partition Size = 46986498. Everything else is zero.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE object_version_info (
  key ascii,
  version bigint,
  acl text,
  chunks int,
  date_created timestamp,
  date_deleted timestamp,
  deleted boolean,
  descriptors text,
  digest text,
  object_size bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, version)
)

Comment: WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=1800000 AND
  compaction={'sstable_size_in_mb': '256', 'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={};'

Comment: Did you disable KeyCache for a reason? disk I/O could be your bottleneck. Do you monitor it?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16721072/2221483

Comment: The key cache was disabled in order to perform more realistic performance testing. We plan on having a few billion keys that we do not expect to be in the cache. Unless it is a necessity of course.

Comment: There is quite a bit of disk I/O due to LCS compaction. I last inserted data three days ago and LCS compaction is still going at 40% disk utilization. Is there a way to estimate when it will finish or is there a way to halt it to see if performance improves?

Comment: look at the number of PendingTasks: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_compaction_metrics_c.html?scroll=concept_ds_kx1_ydr_ck

For tuning the compaction look here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec

There is no silver bullet. It all depends on your work load. Try adjust the settings and measure, measure and measure

Comment: @user3025533 BTW, do you ever change the rows you've written? May be Size-tiered compaction is better choice for you? http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/when-to-use-leveled-compaction

Comment: Thank you. Eliminating the I/O due to the LCS compaction solved the problem.